# How to calculate object's height in pixels from an image?

Tags: image-processing, calculations, forensics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate object size when I have physical pixel size](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23651/calculate-object-size-when-i-have-physical-pixel-size)

I am working on the following formula to calculate distance of object from camera:

```
distance to object (mm) = focal length (mm) * real height of the object (mm) * image height (pixels)
                         ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                         object height (pixels) * sensor height (mm)
```

all other parameters are known except object height in pixels?

Comment: Wait, hold on — do you mean "how do I find out what the height in pixels of a given object _is_?"

Answer (score 5):

That's going to sound amazingly simple but open the image in your image editing software of choice (e.g. The GIMP), pick the "Select" tool, and select a rectangle encompassing your "object". In The GIMP, the size of the select box is displayed in the status bar at the bottom. There you go. Object height in pixels :)

Comment: I think he means how many pixels <i>will</i> some object be in size given the distance from the camera, the focal length, and size and resolution of the sensor.

Comment: @OlinLathrop : "I am working on the following formula to calculate distance of object from camera". So the distance is not known, but all other parameters should be.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of think so too, which in my mind makes this a silly question. (To which this _is_ the right answer.)