# How to obtain a subject's measurement from image

Tags: calculations

I am trying measure real object height from an image. I'm using the below formula

$$ \text{real height [mm]} = \frac{\text{object height [px]}\times \text{pixel size }\left[\mathrm{mm\over px}\right]\times \text{distance [mm]}}{\text{focal length [mm]}} $$

My camera is a Canon EOS 550D. My values are below:

- sensor size: 22.3 x 14.9 mm
- focal length:  30 mm
- distance to object: 1000 mm
- pixel height: 1201

I applied values in this equation but I cannot measure object.

Comment: To calculate the pixel size you also need the image pixel height.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,my object pixel height =802 i converted to mm =212.2 mm then( 16mm(sensor size aprox)*212.2(mm)*1000(mm,distance)/30mm(focal length) can you please advice me about my mistake

Comment: Check this question http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23414/can-we-measure-size-of-an-object-using-exif-data-from-a-photo

Comment: Thanks for reply, one doubt i checked sensor size of Canon_EOS_550D  find out 22.3 x 14.9 mm,how can i use this value in equation,eg 22.3*14.9 or?

Comment: below equation also i tried but i did not get actual measurement (2*distance*(sensor size / focal length)) / number of pixels        (2*1000(mm)*(22.3*14.9(mm))/30mm))/802 can you please help me

Comment: We have a lot of similar questions already. Please search before asking a new one.

Comment: 802 pixels can't convert to 212.2 mm, as the sensor is only 14.9 mm high. You need the image height in pixels so that you can calculate the size of a pixel. If the image height is for example 3000 pixels, 802*14.9/3000 = 3.98 mm.

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is this:

$$ \text{obj. height [units]} = \text{distance [units]} \times \frac{\text{obj. height [px]}}{\text{img height [px]}} \times \frac{\text{sensor height [mm]}}{\text{focal length [mm]}} $$

In your case, you are missing the image height in pixels:

$$ \text{obj. height [mm]} = 1000\,[\mathrm{mm}]\times \frac{1201\,[\mathrm{px}]}{\text{IMAGE [px]}} \times \frac{14.9\,[\mathrm{mm}]}{30\,[\mathrm{mm}]} $$